# Laravel API response conversion into collection

Tags: php, laravel, api

I'm playing with `API` responses for a while and I can't convert them into `Laravel` collection format.

My response after `$users = json_decode($users, true);` is something like that:

```
array:2 [▼
  "@odata.context" => "https://URL/Something.svc/$metadata#Something"
  "value" => array:190 [▼
    0 => array:18 [▶]
    1 => array:18 [▶]
    2 => array:18 [▶]
    3 => array:18 [▶]
    4 => array:18 [▶]
    5 => array:18 [▶]
    6 => array:18 [▶]
    7 => array:18 [▶]
```

I need to convert it into `Laravel` collection so instead of original `json_decode` I have to use:

```
$users = collect(array_values(json_decode($users, true))[1]);
```

It works, but I felt that this is not the right way to do that? Also, I have to use `[1]` at the end. What's if the array is empty and `[1]` does not exist? Do I need to validate if it exists or if there is a proper way to deal with this conversion?

Answer (score 1):

After decoding the data you will have an [associative array](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_associative.asp) where you can access the data inside the 'value' array directly using `$users['value']`, so there is not need to use the **array_values** function.

```
$users = json_decode($users, true);
    if (isset($users['value'])) {
        $usersCollection = collect($users['value']);
    }
```

I guess something like this should work fine.